# Swift UITableView numberOfRowsInSection with ternary operator

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray

The following controller has **numberOfRowsInSection:** ofUITableViewDataSource.

```
class CityList: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

  weak var cityListArray:NSMutableArray? = nil

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.cityListArray?.count
}
}
```

`return self.cityListArray?.count` shows Value of optional type int? not unwrapped did you mean to use '!' or "?"

How can I use ternary operator here, to return 0 if the array was empty?

Objective-C had default value returned 0, if the object is nil.

Comment: Use the nil coalescing operator: `return self.cityListArray?.count ?? 0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers for this. One is already mentioned in the comments of the question.

```
return self.cityListArray?.count ?? 0
```

Which seems to be a shorter than the one which uses a ternary operator, mentioned below.

```
  return (self.cityListArray != nil) ? self.cityListArray!.count : 0
```